# Convert a date interval into rows of individual dates

Tags: sas

In SAS, I have a column with a `start_date` in the past and a column with an `end_date` of today.  I also have a `price` and an `ID`. `ID` is distinct.

I need to pivot the dates vertically to have unique `date`, `price` and `ID`.

START:

```
start         end          price    ID
------------------------------------------
3/26/2017   3/28/2017    3.25     12345678
```

END:

```
ID        price      date
------------------------------
12345678  3.25       3/26/2017 
12345678  3.25       3/27/2017 
12345678  3.25       3/28/2017
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as I interpret the question. (No offence meant.)

You have date interval and you wish to have row for each date between them while retaining ID and price.

First we generate a bit of data.

```
data Begin;
    input start :DATE9. end :DATE9. price ID;
    datalines;
    '26MAR17'd '28MAR17'd 3.25 12345678
    '1JAN17'd '4JAN17'd 5.6 876543221
    ;
run;
```

We always want to sort thins out.

```
proc sort data= begin; by start; run;

data wanted(keep=ID price date); 
    set begin;
    by start; /*Each start date begins the following loop*/
        do while (start <= end); 
            date=start; /*This is just that we get the right name out from output*/
            output; 
            start= start+1;
        end;
run;
```

Please make sure that end>begin or you'll hit endless loop. (Or add comparison to the code.)